# How to connect android application to local computer as a server

Tags: android, node.js, sockets

I am Trying this Socket.IO in my Application
https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat

I am connecting the socket with

```
mSocket =  IO.socket(ip:XXXX);
```

It is throwing `EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR` listener, i connect my applcation
using my computer as a local server.

here is my node js code:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (req,res) {

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

  res.end('Hello World');

});

server.on('listening',function(){

    console.log('ok, server is running');
});

server.listen(3000);        

console.log('yes connected');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chrome I use this to check

chrome://inspect/#devices

Click on PortForwarding . Use Port: 8080 IPAddress and Port:localhost:8080

On your phone ( must be connected via USB to your computer) , go to the address in your phone's chrome browser. Sometimes you need to refresh before your phone can use your localhost.